# How to use fine-tuned bert model in other tasks?

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, roberta-language-model

I fine-tuned a bert (or roberta) model for sequence classification. Can I fine-tune the same model for a different task (QA or Sentiment Analysis)?

Comment: Sure, but you will need to add another head and your model will (start to) forget what it has learned for sequence classification. An alternative is a multitask learning approach.